# How to write this list in Typescript? it is currently in Javascript, It is list of cars,

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to write this list in Typescript?
I know the code works in TypeScript, but I want the list to have declarative types. it is currently in Javascript, it is list of cars :

```
const list_of_cars = [{
  type: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  year: 2009
},
  type: "Ford",
  model: "Mustang",
  year: 1969
}];
```

I know have tried `const car: { type: string, model: string, year: number } =`

Comment: Your existing code is perfectly valid and properly typed TypeScript

Comment: how? its javascript? there are not types declared

Comment: Which is also valid syntax in TypeScript. TypeScript will infer the type properly. There's no need for anything else.

Comment: but I want it written properly in TypeScript.

Comment: I think you should have a go at the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/) to really learn what typescript is.

Comment: It *is* written properly in TypeScript. If I were writing TypeScript and needed to declare such an array, I'd do it exactly as you already have it with no modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also a valid in typescript. If you want in types then you can write it like this

```
const list_of_cars:{type:string, model:string,year:number}[] = [{
  type: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  year: 2009
},{
  type: "Ford",
  model: "Mustang",
  year: 1969
}];
```

**OR you can declare an type and use that**

```
type car={type:string, model:string,year:number}
const list_of_cars : car[] = [{
  type: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  year: 2009
},{
  type: "Ford",
  model: "Mustang",
  year: 1969
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically, you can define a type or interface for specific objects and specify the individual types for each attribute. You can then define your list as an array of the specific interface or type you defined.

Example:

```
interface Car {
 type: string
 model: string
 year: number
}

const listOfCars: Car[] = [{
  type: "Toyota",
  model: "Corolla",
  year: 2009
},
  type: "Ford",
  model: "Mustang",
  year: 1969
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of our strictest repos at work we declare explicit types on array containers, which would look like this, if you're interested in seeing it organised professionally:

```js
interface CarType {
    type: string
    model: string
    year: number
}

type CarsType = CarType[]

const list_of_cars: CarsType = [
    { type: 'Toyota', model: 'Corolla', year: 2009 },
    { type: 'Ford', model: 'Mustang', year: 1969 },
]
```